# Extract functions from struct init

Tags: swift, struct, initialization

I'm trying to refactor struct's init method. Init receives dictionary and initialises struct from it. There are several long parsing logic parts (iterating through arrays, etc) and init is too long. I was trying to extract this logic to separate functions (kudos to new Xcode refactoring features!) but compiler tells me:

> `self` used before all stored properties are initialized

Is there any way to refactor my messy init?
I came to idea of creating separate `Parser` class but the res of the model (really big project) parses JSON in each struct `init`. So creating this `Parser` class will make the project inconsistent...

Sample code:

```
struct Example {
    let intParam: Int
    let dates: [Date]

    // Current implementation
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.intParam = dictionary["intParam"] as? Int ?? 0
        var dates: [Date] = []
        // long parsing here
        self.dates = dates
    }

    // Desired implementation
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.intParam = dictionary["intParam"] as? Int ?? 0
        self.dates = parseDates(dictionary)
    }

    private func parseDates(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) -> [Date] {
        var dates: [Date] = []
        // long parsing here
        return dates
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense, and your results cannot be reproduced. You say you get "self used before all stored properties are initialized", but I don't; we never get to that point, because `dictionary["intParam"] ?? 0` doesn't compile.

Comment: You could make the function static

Comment: Also, the question itself seems to make no sense. You cannot have a dictionary of `[String:Int]` that is also a dictionary of `[String:Date]`. I don't see where you think you're going with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try making `parseDates` a static function.

```
  // Desired implementation
  init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.intParam = dictionary["intParam"] as? Int ?? 0
    self.dates = Example.parseDates(dictionary)
  }

  private static func parseDates(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) -> [Date] {
    var dates: [Date] = []
      // long parsing here
     return dates
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do seems rather odd, but this would get you your "desired implementation":

```
init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.intParam = dictionary["intParam"] as? Int ?? 0
    self.dates = Example.parseDates(dictionary)
}

private static func parseDates(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) -> [Date] {
    var dates: [Date] = []
    // long parsing here
    return dates
}
```

However, I don't see what you think this gets you. If this parsing operation is not needed anywhere else, and you merely want it to look neater, why not use a local function?

```
init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.intParam = dictionary["intParam"] as? Int ?? 0
    func parseDates(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) -> [Date] {
        var dates: [Date] = []
        // long parsing here
        return dates
    }
    self.dates = parseDates(dictionary)
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why do you think that's an odd solution? This is a sample code. Real init size right now is 100+ lines so I'm trying to make it more readable...

Comment: I don't see why it gets more readable just because the code is factored out into a method. If this is one-time code, that makes it _less_ readable, as it is misleading. That's why I suggest using a local function. Now _that_ is more readable!

Comment: Thanks. In your first code all properties assignments are compact and follow each other. It is easy to read. In the second code you'll have code blocks between each property assignment. I don't see how second suggested solution makes it more readable that just plain 100+ lines init without local functions. I don't think functions can be used only in cases when code is reused. I think code separation into logic peaces is proper functions usage too. To make first solution less missleading you can add `fileprivate` so it will be obvious that this static method never called outside this file.

Comment: Fair enough but note that we are now in the realm of pure opinion. Chacun à son goût.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll give an "answer" to the @bhzag as he was the first with desired solution. +1 for you

Comment: Actually the commenter @dan was first. :) We merely illustrated what he had already said. Please note that it took extra time to come up with a working solution because, as I said in my comments, the code _you_ gave didn't compile because the expression `dictionary["intParam"] ?? 0` makes no sense.